# Disable Inspections for a specific PsiElement subclass

Tags: java, intellij-plugin, intellij-inspections

I developed a Custom Language plugin based on this [this tutorial](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/custom-language-support-tutorial.html).

Now I'd like to disable/suppress Inspection with message `Non-ASCII characters in an identifier` for specific identifiers via Plugin API. I use these identifiers which start with '#' as sections headers and do not want any default highlightning/inspections for them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ will automatically add a suppress option when you add a quick fix (then go "right") from there. If you only want a suppress quick fix, you can add it like this in your holder.registerProblem(...)

```
private static class QuickFixSuppress implements SuppressQuickFix {
  @NotNull private static final String SUPPRESS_ID = new EjbBusinessMethodPublicInspection().getSuppressId();

  @Override
  public boolean isAvailable(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull PsiElement psiElement) {
    return psiElement instanceof PsiMethod;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isSuppressAll() {
    return false;
  }

  @Nls
  @NotNull
  @Override
  public String getFamilyName() {
    return "Suppress " + SUPPRESS_ID;
  }

  @Override
  public void applyFix(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull ProblemDescriptor problemDescriptor) {
    final PsiElement element = problemDescriptor.getPsiElement();
    if (element instanceof PsiMethod) {
      PsiMethod psiMethod = (PsiMethod) element;
      JavaSuppressionUtil.addSuppressAnnotation(project, psiMethod, psiMethod, SUPPRESS_ID);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not get how to use this class `QuickFixSuppress`. How do I use it with `holder.registerProblem`?